# Android Manifest according screen size

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-orientation

is it possible to have multiple Manifest files for different screen sizes.

Im asking, because I have an app that should be phone and tablet optimized.

But I want to lock the "phone version" in portrait, while the "tablet version" should have portrait and landscape enabled.

So the easiest way for me would be, to let android handle orientation changes and I would only set android:screenOrientation="portrait" in the manifest file.

Is there a way to do something like "layout-sw600dp" for manifest or to link a value in the manifest android:screenOrientation="@string/portrait_landscape_enabled"

where "@string/portrait_landscape_enabled" will be set in values-sw600dp etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set screen orientation in code depending on device application running on

```
if(device is phone)
{
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);  
}
```

This is just a clue.

Comment: That seems to be a possibility ... Not the most elegant, since I have to check it in every Activity. What will hapen if I do that in the onCreate(). Would the first Activity be visible for a short periode and will be replaced with the recreated (with the correcto orientation) one?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this thing . I don't think that making multiple manifest files is possible in android.

Answer (score 0):

You can set by programmatically,  i will write just code snippet refer and try yourself. it's not possible to add more manifest file.

```
    Button buttonSetPortrait = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setPortrait);
    Button buttonSetLandscape = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setLandscape);

    buttonSetPortrait.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
 }});

    buttonSetLandscape.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
 }});
}
```